# Sepcify two minimum required versions for a package

Tags: cmake

My CMake project depends on a package which had a bug. The bug has been fixed in  bugfix releases for two different feature branches; let's say that the bug is fixed in 2.4.4 and 2.5.1, but is still present in 2.4.3 and 2.5.0. Some of my users are stuck with the 2.4 feature train of the dependence package and others with 2.5, so I have the problem to enforce 2.4.4 for the former and 2.5.1 for the latter. How can I do this when calling find_package? If I call:

```
find_package(ExternalPackage 2.4.4 REQUIRED)
```

then it will be ok for people with 2.4, but this will also allow for 2.5.0; in the same way, if I call:

```
find_package(ExternalPackage 2.5.1 REQUIRED)
```

then my code will not work with 2.4.x. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package version checks are done by the version file provided by the package. The only thing that can affect it's behaviour is the `EXACT` parameter you can send to `find_package`.

My recommendation would be to check for version `2.4.4`, but assert that the version is not `2.5.0`.

```
if(ExternalPackage_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL "2.5.0")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "ExternalPackage must not be version 2.5.0. 2.4.4 or 2.5.1 or better is required.")
endif()
```

Comment: This seems a neat and working solution, I'll go  with this. Thanks!